# Can we have Rijndael s-boxes constructed using reducible polynomials?

Tags: aes, block-cipher, finite-field, s-boxes, rijndael

Is it necessary for the Rijnael polynomial to be irreducible? Can we have s-boxes constructed using reducible polynomials? If not what is the mathematical property that is obstructing to do so?

Comment: You could....but its meant to protect against shift frequency atks...by having an irreducible polynomial equation it is difficult to determine the shift interval

Comment: Can you please elaborate. If possible please provide an example where an secure S - box is constructed using a reducible polynomial. @light bringer

Answer (score 3):

As [noted by poncho](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/44421/is-it-necessary-for-the-rijndael-polynomial-to-be-primitive?rq=1#comment101469_44423) in the comments to your previous question, the [Rijndael S-box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_S-box) is defined based on the multiplicative inverse of the input byte in a particular representation of the finite field $GF(2^8)$, where the representation is defined by the choice of the reduction polynomial.

However, in order to represent a [finite field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field) using addition and multiplication of polynomials modulo some reduction polynomial, the reduction polynomial must be irreducible.  If it isn't, the resulting algebraic structure will not be a field, and in particular, not all non-zero elements will have multiplicative inverses.

Of course, you could simply dispense with the finite field inverses entirely, and just construct your S-box in some other way.  As the Rijndael authors note in section 7.2 of the [Rijndael AES proposal](http://csrc.nist.gov/archive/aes/rijndael/Rijndael-ammended.pdf#page=28):

> Note: other S-boxes can be found that satisfy the criteria above. In the case of suspicion of a trapdoor being built into the cipher, the current S-box might be replaced by another one. The cipher structure and number of rounds as defined even allow the use of an S-box that does not optimise the differential and linear cryptanalysis properties (criteria 2 and 3). Even an S-box that is “average” in this respect is likely to provide enough resistance against differential and linear cryptanalysis.